# Send character limit to transifex using babel or anything else

Tags: python, jinja2, python-babel, transifex

Is there a way to set character limits for a translation from within the template?

I am currently using babel to generate pot files to push them to transifex. one of the tags i am sending is the translators comments

```
-c TAG, --add-comments=TAG
```

I was wondering if there is a way i can set the character limits as well in my template and set it in the pot file to be set in transifex

Answer (score 1):

At the moment [XLIFF](http://docs.transifex.com/developer/formats/xliff) is the only file format that supports this feature. PO files seem to not have native support for such type of information. If this is really important to you, you might want to use the [Resource Strings API](http://docs.transifex.com/developer/api/resource_strings) endpoint to set character limits though.